# Turn off table row overflow across pages using a Google Apps Script for a Google Doc

Tags: google-apps-script, google-docs, google-docs-api

Is there a Google Apps Script attribute or method to turn off the 'Allow row to overflow across pages' row option for a table in an existing Google Doc?

I have the abbreviated code below that correctly retrieves the table, but the attribute value is not valid.

```
var body = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument().getBody();
var tables = body.getTables();
  for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
    var table = tables[i];
    var rows = table.getNumRows();
    for (var j = 0; j < rows; j++) {
      var row = table.getRow(j);
      row.setAttributes({ "allowBreakAcrossPages": false });
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to uncheck "Allow row to overflow across pages" of the table property.
- You want to achieve this using Google Apps Script.

Unfortunately, it seems that in the current stage, there are no methods for unchecking it with the Google Document service (DocumentApp). But, fortunately, when Google Docs API is used, this can be achieved. In this answer, I would like to propose using Google Docs API. The sample script is as follows.

#### Sample script:

Before you use this script, [please enable Google Docs API at Advanced Google services](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/advanced#enable_advanced_services).

And, please set the table index you want to use. In this sample, the 1st table in the Document is used with `const table = body.getTables()[0];`.

```js
function myFunction() {
  const doc = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
  const documentId = doc.getId();
  const body = doc.getBody();
  const table = body.getTables()[0]; // Please set the index of the table.
  const index = Docs.Documents.get(documentId).body.content[body.getChildIndex(table) + 1].startIndex;
  const requests = [{
    updateTableRowStyle: {
      tableRowStyle: { preventOverflow: true },
      tableStartLocation: { index },
      fields: "preventOverflow",
    }
  }];
  Docs.Documents.batchUpdate({ requests }, documentId);
}
```

- When this script is run, the checkbox of "Allow row to overflow across pages" is unchecked. If you want to check it, please modify `preventOverflow: true` to `preventOverflow: false`.

#### References:

- [Method: documents.batchUpdate](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/batchUpdate)
- [UpdateTableRowStyleRequest](https://developers.google.com/docs/api/reference/rest/v1/documents/request#updatetablerowstylerequest)